# Как передать в js значение из php, полученное из БД

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?
  $a_txt = "text";   // значение передается в js
  $b_txt = $text_bd; // значение из БД, не передается в js
?>

<script>
  var a_txt = '<?=$a_txt;?>';
  var b_txt = '<?=$b_txt;?>';
  ...
</script>
```

Почему значение $b_txt не передается в js, подскажите, как его передать?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" class="b_txt" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($b_txt); ?>">.. let b = document.querySelector('.b_txt').value;`.. А так-то, переменная $b_txt не пустая?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, InDevX!

```
<? $b_txt = $text_bd; ?>

<input type="hidden" class="b_txt" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($b_txt); ?>">

<script>
  let b_txt = document.querySelector('.b_txt').value;
  ...
</script>
```